# Creating Ord instances with newtype wrapping

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype

Given a datatype such as

```
data Foo = Bar | Baz | Qux
```

and I wish to have multiple different orderings for this type, is the following the most common/standard way to achieve this?

```
newtype FooPriorityA = FooPriorityA { unFooPriorityA :: Foo }

instance Ord FooPriorityA where
    compare (FooPriorityA x) (FooPriorityA y) = f x `compare` f y
        where f :: Foo -> Int
              f Baz = 1
              f Bar = 2
              f Qux = 3

newtype FooPriorityB = FooPriorityB ... and so on
```

Is delegating to Int's Ord instance like that crazy? It feels safer and a whole lot less work than writing out the n^2 comparisons for `compare`.

Any obvious flaws I might have overlooked with this "hack"? Is it even a "hack"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need O(*n*) (2​*n* - 1, to be precise) definitions to specify a total order, as long as you specify the cases in increasing order of priority:

```
instance Ord FooPriorityA where
    compare (FooPriorityA x) (FooPriorityA y) | x == y = EQ   -- Use the Eq instance
                                              -- Bar is the smallest
                                              | x == Bar = LT
                                              | y == Bar = GT
                                              -- Baz is the next smallest
                                              | x == Baz = LT
                                              | y == Baz = GT
                                              -- Proceed in the desired order.
                                              -- You don't need to say anything
                                              -- explicit about the largest value
```

The first case (`x == y`) covers O(n) possibilities. Each case that follows may look incomplete, but it carries the implied information that each preceding case is false. For example, `x == Bar = LT` does not mean that *every* case where `x == Bar` evaluates to `LT`; the case where `x == Bar && y == Bar` is already handled, so the second case is really implicitly `x == Bar && y /= Bar`.

Likewise, case 4 (`x == Baz`) carries the assumption that `y /= Baz` (implied by the failure of case 1 to match) and `y /= Bar` (implied by the failure of case 3 to match). Therefore, any remaining possible value for `y` is, in fact, greater than `Baz`.

The further down the list you go, the fewer unhandled cases remain. By the end, you don't need to say anything explicit about the largest item; all the information about how it compares to the other *n* - 1 items has already been captured by the preceding cases.

---

Also, keep in mind that your definition of `f` is one half (`fromEnum`) of the minimum implementation of an instance of the `Enum` class, which you could then use to define your `Ord` instance.

```
instance Enum FooPriorityA where
     fromEnum Bar = 1
     fromEnum Baz = 2
     fromEnum Qux = 3
     toEnum 1 = Bar
     toEnum 2 = Baz
     toEnum 3 = Qux

instance Ord FooPriorityA where
    compare x y = compare (fromEnum x) (fromEnum y)
    -- compare = compare `on` Data.Function.fromEnum
```

Comment: That's some fantastic information, thanks. The observation about the relationship between my `f` and the `Enum` typeclass is fascinating.

Answer (score 7):

This is absolutely reasonable. In fact, you can use [the `comparing` function from `Data.Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) to make this even more direct:

```
instance Ord FooPriorityA where
  compare (FooPriorityA x) (FooPriorityA y) = comparing f x y
    where f :: Foo -> Int
          f Baz = 1
          f Bar = 2
          f Qux = 3
```

Though depending on your preferences, the version with `compare` might be more to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a function to generate the mapping from `Foo` to `Int` based on a list that represents the ordering you want:

```
import Data.List

data Foo = Bar | Baz | Qux deriving Eq

newtype FooPriorityA = FooPriorityA { unFooPriorityA :: Foo } deriving Eq

fooOrdering :: [Foo] -> Foo -> Foo -> Ordering
fooOrdering orderedList a b = f a `compare` f b
    where f x = elemIndex x orderedList

instance Ord FooPriorityA where
    compare (FooPriorityA x) (FooPriorityA y) = fooOrdering [Baz, Bar, Qux] x y
```

You could even add an assertion to make sure that all elements occur exactly once in the list.

Comment: I think I prefer the pattern match internally to the instance, mainly because while your `fooOrdering` saves some characters, it makes it possible to provide some pretty non-sensical values, e.g., [Bar, Bar, Bar, Bar]. Whereas pattern matching will give warnings for such things. You could totally stuff up the Ints, though, I guess.

Comment: @SimonF: I was thinking you'd prevent non-sensical values by adding an assertion to make sure that all elements occur exactly once in the list. But you are right, the compiler will already do that for pattern matching.

Comment: The other thing I don't like about my solution is that it has to iterate the list at runtime for every comparison. Would be nice to have a static map constructed at compile-time (or at least memoized after first use).